# gitlab mirroring (Pull from a remote repository)

Tags: bitbucket, gitlab, mirroring

I try to use the gitlab "mirroring" feature to mirror a project stored on bitbucket.

I configured the project mirror on: "**Settings**->**Repository**->**Pull from a remote repository**" but it seems to not work.

I see this [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7JdG.png) and after some time it fails...

Did someone has this problem using https://gitlab.com ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you use/have the good credentials and access rights for the bitbucket project ?

Comment: yes, I'm using it via https (username+password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience, mirroring a project from BitBucket to GitLab on https://gitlab.com is extremely slow. It takes up to an hour or even two before it successfully pulls in any changes.

It also looks like as soon as it's successfully mirrored, the trigger is done again immediately to put the mirror into the "queue" again, but this would take another hour or so.

I would advise using self-hosted GitLab if you are able to, as mirroring is basically instantaneous then.